# Relocate recent commits to another branch

Tags: git

I created a branch but I forgot to switch to this branch (`menu`). I did all commits on `master`. How can I swap these two branches (`master` with the new branch, `menu`)? I did all commits on `master` by mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply swap the branch names. (I hope you haven't pushed those commits yet, though!)

Find out what the first commit is on `master` that should have been on the `menu` branch using `git log`. For instance, say it is commit `abcdef`.

Then, `git checkout abcdef^ -b new-master` to check out the commit BEFORE that first commit into a new branch `new-master`.

Then, rename the `master` branch to `menu`, and the `new-master` branch to `master`, using `git branch -m master menu` and `git branch -m new-master master`.

*UPDATE*

Reading your post again, I think that your `menu` branch is already at the last good commit in `master`. So, all you have to do is rename the branch names.
That is because, if you `git checkout menu`, you'll find yourself back at the point just before the 'wrong' commits were made.

In this case you can't rename `master` to `menu` because that branch already exists, so you'll have to use a temporary branch name:

```
git branch -m master whoops
git branch -m menu master
git branch -m whoops menu
```